# Why does Emacs use a positive value for setting timezones west of UTC (England)?

Tags: emacs

I'm using a fairly recent version of Emacs Trunk on OSX 10.6.8.

I'm having trouble understanding why Los Angeles would be UTC+8 when England is 8 hours ahead of Los Angeles.  It should be UTC-8.  Is there a bug in Emacs Trunk where the positive and negatives are reversed when it comes to timezone setting?

`(setenv "TZ" "UTC-8")` yields the *wrong* date / time for Los Angeles, California -- i.e., it is 16 hours ahead.

`(setenv "TZ" "UTC+8")` yields the *correct* date / time for Los Angeles, California.

Comment: Is this actually emacs, or is it whatever controls your timezone stuff?

Comment: @MrBones:  You are correct -- lunaryorn has expanded upon your initial thoughts about Emacs not being the controlling factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not specific to Emacs, and it is not a bug either.  It's POSIX :)

The meaning of `TZ` is specified in [IEEE Std 1003.1, Base Definitions, 8.3 Other Environment Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> […]
>
> The expanded format (for all TZ s whose value does not have a  as the first character) is as follows:
>
> stdoffset[dst[offset][,start[/time],end[/time]]]
>
> Where:
>
> std and dst
>
> Indicate no less than three, nor more than {TZNAME_MAX}, bytes that are the designation for the standard (std) or the alternative (dst -such as Daylight Savings Time) timezone. Only std is required; if dst is missing, then the alternative time does not apply in this locale.
>   Each of these fields may occur in either of two formats quoted or unquoted:
>
> […]
>
> offset
>
> Indicates the value **added to the local time** to arrive at Coordinated Universal Time. The offset has the form:
>
> […]

`UTC+8` does not mean “UTC plus 8 hours”, but rather “the timezone, which is 8 hours *behind* UTC”, or more precisely, the timezone to whose local time 8 hours must be added to get UTC.

Los Angeles is 8 hours behind UTC, so you need to add 8 hours to Los Angeles local time to get UTC time, which gives you `TZ=UTF+8`.  `TZ=UTF-8` gives you the local time of Shangai, which is 8 hours ahead of UTC, so you must add -8 hours to the local time to get UTC.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to better understand how setting timezones is derived -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)